# Why does Jing not allow a colon (":") in an id attribute?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, relaxng

I've been banging my head against xsd:ID not allowing a colon (":") in an id attribute.  I first noticed this when using James Clark's nxml-mode in Emacs as it validated an XHTML file I was working with.  I then ran the XHTML file against the RNG (provided with nxml-mode-20041004) using Jing and received the following error(s):

```
error: value of attribute "id" is invalid; must be an XML name without colons
```

Most of the W3 pages I've seen indicate that a colon is valid. Then I found this, http://www.w3.org/XML/xml-19980210-errata#E98, which I take to mean: "you shouldn't use a colon in an id attribute, but you should be allowed to." Given that interpretation, I'm stumped why Jing says I can't.

Thank you,
Zachary

Comment: Here's the most current version of the document: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-common-syn

Comment: Hi BoltClock.  Yes, that is one of the W3 pages I was referring to.  From this link, http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#id, "Values of type ID must match the Name production."  There is a link for "the Name production" that shows the valid characters which, if I'm reading `NameStartChar' correctly, indicates that a colon is valid.  So, again if I'm reading this correctly, I should be able to make something like "id=':::::'".  If I am not reading this correctly, anybody, please tell me how to read this. :)   Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at two subtly different definitions here. xsd:ID is [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#ID) in terms of the NCName type in [Namespaces in XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-decl) and the ID type of the base XML standard is defined in terms of the [Name](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name) type. Both share the following definition:

```
NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | 
    [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | 
    [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | 
    [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | 
    [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
NameChar ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | 
    [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
Name ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
```

NCName is defined as:

```
NCName ::=  Name - (Char* ':' Char*)
```

which is Name minus the colon.

The result of this is that in terms of XML itself, the value of something typed as ID can contain a colon. In terms of anything that uses the XML Schema datatypes (such as your RelaxNG schema) there is more restricted data type in use which forbids the use of the colon. Anything that uses an XML Schema compliant attribute will be valid against the base definition but not necessarily the other way around.

Comment: Hi, Nic.  Thank you very much.  I can see the difference, in at least the two different productions, now.  And I am beginning to see the difference between xsd:ID and the ID type in the W3C documentation, but that's something I think I can resolve on my own with a little more time.  I'll need to read your answer, think about it, and read it again, at least a couple of times before it sinks in.  Thanks again!

Comment: The issue I had was that my ID started with a digit, while this wants it to start with a letter before the digits comes. Hope this helps anyone else.